# boto shows empty list when querying load balancers from AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-elb

I'm using boto v2.46.1 to query the AWS API in order to list ELB instances.

There is one classic load balancer in region `us-east-1`.

All my tries however produce simply an empty list. I've tried:

- direct access in Python shell:

  ```
  >>> from boto.ec2 import elb
  >>> conn = elb.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id="...", aws_secret_access_key="...")
  >>> conn.get_all_load_balancers()
  []
  ```
- via the `aws` command line tools (using `boto` under the hood, too)
- via Ansible's `ec2_elb_facts` module (where the issue appeared first)

I made sure, that

- I've used the correct region.
- I'm allowed to see anything by using an API user with admin rights.

Is there anything obvious, that I missed? Why is my load balancer not found in this rather trivial set-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me!

I did the following:

- Created a Classic Load Balancer
- Tested with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws elb describe-load-balancers` command -- it listed my Load Balancer
- Ran your code, it returned `[LoadBalancer:stackoverflow]`

Check that you can view it with the AWS CLI. If you made an Application Load Balancer, it will only show up using the `elbv2` API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I knew it was something trivial. Apparently I was misguided, and it's not a "Classic" but an "Application" load balancer. Works like a charm with `aws elbv2`.